# What exactly is this piece of electronics?

Tags: identification, components, radio

I've come across a component which I have not been able to find on Google. My guess is that it could be a sort of radio controller, since I recognise an antenna and a 27M oscillator.

I have included pictures of the component below, the codes are XT-009T RTTE for the front and TX-2B for the microprocessor at the back.

Any help is very appreciated.

[image: Image of the front side of the component.]

[image: Image of the back side of the component.]

Comment: So it is some sort of radio, but not anything standard which would make it any famous on Google.

Comment: Might be a garage door opener...

Comment: remote control for a cheap RC toy ... FWD and REV control on left ... steering control on right

Comment: Without at least the part number of the (supposedly) main chip on the back side, it's impossible to give even an educated guess. Please, post a better photo or try and read the parts number and add them to your post.

Comment: If I came across this piece, I'd immediately throw it in the trash.   But that's just me....

Comment: 27MHZ RC toy PCB, (xtal = 27.145MHZ).  Marking on top right possibly a trade mark, (HiTec ??)

Comment: Also quite likely illegal to use anywhere outside China. Check if it lists relevant compliance to be used in the country where you live (FCC mark, CE mark etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheap [remote control board](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32805986813.html) used for toys.